# Animated Splash screen -Implement with Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, firebase-security, bloc

I'm trying to run an animated splash screen,
My issue is I can't figure out if they method I am using is a safe one

Main.dart file
below
//////////////

```
    void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Take Note',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const SplashScreen(),
      routes: {
        //
        // Routes for the app
        createOrUpdateNoteRoute: (context) => const CreateUpdateNoteView(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

In my splash_screen.dart file I have created a method

```
  void _playVideo() async {
    _controller.play();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(FirebaseAuthProvider()),
          child: const HomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So the code works however I am wondering how to implement this with my AuthBloc + State + Events structure, feel like Navifator/Material Page Route isn't the optimal/safe way to do so.